# Datasource creation in JBOSS for DB2

Tags: java, jboss, db2

How JBOSS uses db2-ds.xml file to create datasource object for DB2?

Answer (score 0):

If it is about how to create a DataSource you copy $JBOSS_HOME\docs\examples\jca\db2-ds.xml to $JBOSS_HOME\server\default\deploy and customize the settings to fit your JDBC connection-url,user-name etc.

EDIT:
Jboss reads this file, and periodically checks for updates (if configured) and sets up a DataSource which is registered in JNDI and provides a pool of connections depending on underlying driver-class. To see how this is done in detail you should throw a glance into the sourcecode. Search for "-ds.xml" a good startingpoint is: $JBOSS_SRC\console\src\main\org\jboss\console\manager\DeploymentFileRepository.java which looks for "-ds.xml" files.

Comment: No ,My question was about how JBOSS uses this XML file and finally create and register the datasource with JNDI